# WPF camera animation issue

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have a 3D model in WPF and im trying to make an animation that makes the camera go around my model. I have the following code:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RegisterName("thisWindow", this);
        }

private Model3DGroup MainModel3Dgroup = new Model3DGroup();
private PerspectiveCamera TheCamera;
private double CameraPhi = Math.PI / 6.0;
private double CameraTheta = Math.PI / 6.0;
private double CameraR = 35.0;

private Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
private DependencyProperty CameraPhiProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CameraPhiProperty", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow));

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Define model, lights and everthing
        Animations();
    }
private void RotateAroundTower()
    {
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
        animation.From = 0.0;
        animation.To = 360.0;
        animation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        animation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;

        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, "thisWindow");

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(CameraPhiProperty));
    }

private void PositionCamera()
    {
        // Translates CameraPhi and CameraTheta to coordinates and positions the camera accordingly
    }
```

Everything that I have of the animation is pieced together from what i found on msdn, but it seems to me that my problem is that animation changes the DependencyProperty CameraPhiProperty object, and that PositionCamera is never called.
How can i pass the value from my DependencyProperty to my CameraPhi and call PositionCamera?
Or is there a cleaner solution to animating this?

Comment: And what do you think suppose to call `PositionCamera()`? It's not defined as dependency property [callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745795%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), nor it's called anywhere.

Comment: This is the first time im using dependency properties so i have no idea how those work. That was kind of my question, how i can make sure that my PositionCamera gets called

Comment: At the moment my PositionCamera is being called when i press anything on my keybord, but it isnt relevant code for the issue so i didnt include it.

Comment: If you want to change other properties for each animation tick, then rather create type to hold all such properties and write custom animation for this type. More likely this was already asked and answered, google for e.g. "wpf rotate camera".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rotate cammera around center of object wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487725/rotate-cammera-around-center-of-object-wpf)